# html element not working inside radio button list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have radio button list and inside one of its itemlists I have html input type="text".

When I select the option with input text field, and then click on the text field the focus gets lost and focus shifts to radio button list item that is selected.

Here is the display what I am trying to achieve

[image]

When I click on "Dealer Name" the focus gets shifted to Dealer radio button and so user can not type "Dealer Name"

This above behavior is happening in firefox. In Chrome it's not causing any problem

**UPDATED**:

This is the code I used when selected index change

```
$("#rOD").change(function () {
        if ($("#rOD input:checked").val() == "Dealer") { $("#txtDName").removeAttr("disabled"); }
        else { $("#txtDName").attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
    });
```

I have tried using following code to change focus

```
function fc(elem) {
        $("#rOD").focusout();
        $(elem).focus();
    }
```

And this is the markup

```
<asp:RadioButtonList Font-Size="Small" ID="rOD" data-toggle="popover" title="Field required"
        data-content="Please Select" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Vertical">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Owner" Value="Owner">Owner</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Dealer" Value="Dealer">Dealer&nbsp <input type="text" id="txtDName" onclick="return fc(this);" placeholder="Dealer Name" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="popover" title="Field required" data-content="Please Select" style="width:150px"  /> </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: where is your code? and post a jsfiddle

Comment: Please show your code,

Comment: @gulty I have updated my question with code

Comment: @securedeveloper Updated my question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `jQuery` code:-

```
$("#rOD").click(function (e) {
    $("#rOD input:checked").next().find('input').focus();
});
$("#rOD").change(function (e) {
    if ($("#rOD input:checked").val() == "Dealer") {
        $("#txtDName").removeAttr("disabled");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else { 
        $("#txtDName").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#rOD").change(function () {
    if ($("#rOD input:checked").val() == "Dealer") { $("#txtDName").removeAttr("disabled"); $("#txtDName").focus(); }
    else { $("#txtDName").attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
   });
});

function fc(elem) {
   $(elem).focus();
}
```

here is the result,

[image: Code Result]

Comment: you copied code from question. u didnt change anything

Comment: I have just put your piece of code to `$(document).ready(function(){});` function,

Comment: read the question first. I said it's NOT working in firefox. it's working in other browsers

Comment: I change my code, and now it is working fine with fire fox, (thumbs up!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68719/discussion-between-securedeveloper-and-fali).